# AAPT error mismatched tag tried everything so far what am doing wrong

Tags: layout, textview, tags, android-relativelayout, cardview

very new to coding atm and have this error can anyone help me please.

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movieImageID"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieTitleID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Movie Title"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieReleaseID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:text="Released"
                android:layout_below="@id/movieTitleID"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieCatID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/movieReleaseID"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:text="Category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.Cardview>
</LinearLayout>
```

error i get:-AndroidStudioProjects\MovieDirectory\app\src\main\res\layout\movie_row.xml:53: AAPT: error: mismatched tag.

i manage to fix one error and get another so any help greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are closing the CardView and  RelativeLayout
instead of wrapping the children views inside them. The issue is with the tags.  Check the comments in the solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <!--Issue here Change from /> to > -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"> <!-- Issue here Change from /> to > -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movieImageID"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieTitleID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Movie Title"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieReleaseID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/movieTitleID"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Released" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieCatID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/movieReleaseID"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movieImageID"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Category" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```